# Problem transferring ether to contract (Error: transact to EtherInteractionTest.deposit errored: VM error: revert)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, remix

I'm trying to test a simple contract to deposit and withdraw ether in remix.

**Code:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract EtherInteractionTest {
    function withdraw() public {
        msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
    function deposit(uint256 amount) payable public {
        require(msg.value == amount);
    }

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
This is the error I get:
transact to EtherInteractionTest.deposit errored: VM error: revert.
revert  The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value.  Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

**Remix screen:**

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code requires that the `msg.value` equals the `amount` parameter. Yet, your remix screenshot shows you are sending a 0 value tx with an amount of 10 as the parameter.

This fails the `require` statement, and causes a revert.

Make sure your parameter and tx value are the same.